# Why the change in output of a sigmoid neuron is a linear function of change in weights and change in bias?

Tags: neural-networks

I read this chapter from Michael Neilson book http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

which claims by quoting the following equation, equation no. 5

$$
\delta output \approx \sum_j\frac{\delta output}{\delta w_j}\Delta w_j + \frac{\delta output}{\delta b}\Delta b
$$

I didn't get how he came up with this equation. Can you help me understand it?

Answer (score 4):

He's not saying that the output is a linear function of the weights and biases. This can't be true because the activation function is sigmoidal. He's saying that: if you were to apply a small change $\Delta W$ to the weights and a small change $\Delta b$ to the bias, this would cause a small change $\Delta \text{output}$ to the output. And, $\Delta \text{output}$ would be approximately linear with respect to $\Delta W$ and $\Delta b$. The reason is that, because the activation function is smooth, it's possible to construct a local linear approximation, which is valid in the vicinity of the original $W$ and $b$.

Think about a first-order [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) approximation ([here's a good illustration)](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/07TaylorSeries/). Imagine a smooth, nonlinear function in 1d. Pick a point on the curve and draw a tangent line at that point (i.e. a line that passes through the point, and whose slope is equal to that of the nonlinear function at that point). If you step away from the point by a small amount, the value of the the line at your new point will be close to the value of the original function at the new point. This means that you can locally approximate the nonlinear function with a straight line. But, if you step away too far, the approximation won't be valid anymore. The same concept applies in higher dimensions (e.g. in the case of the sigmoidal activation function with multiple weight parameters). In this case, the linear approximation is a hyperplane instead of a line.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is simply the derivative of the output of the sigmoid perceptron. I will try to explain it, and then I will point you to some further resources.

The equation (5) comes from taking the partial derivatives of equation (4) and ignoring the x inputs. We want to understand how the output changes when the x inputs are constant (when they're constant they don't change the output) - but when we do change the parameters w and b as if they are the inputs. The equation shows how much of the change in the output comes from (is attributable to) each input. When one of the inputs, let's say the bias b, increases by 1, and everything else stays the same, how much would the output change ? This equation, if solved for a specific perceptron, gives us a way to calculate this.

If you would like to be able to go the full way, like he did, from (4) to (5), I recommend the Khan academy calculus class, which is really excellent. It delivers the material in small pieces followed by exercises. You could focus on just the derivation sections from here: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus

Comment: i've tried taking the partial derivative but could not get the same result, can you help me by explaining the steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

If first explanation is complex to you, please visit explanation 2.

**EXPLANATION 1**

Draw the graph of **Change of Weights vs change of output** and **Change of bias vs Change of output**. You'll get linear graphs in both cases. Slope of both lines depends how much change of each terms affect the overall change of output. The more it influences the output, the steeper the graph!

NB: We are talking about change of output (linear graph) here and not about the graph of Sigmoid function (curved graph). If you're still confused, please leave a comment, so that I'll post graphs for you!

**EXPLANATION 2**

Your school does some calculation with internal score and final exam score to decide your semester GPA and they have a formula for it. The formula is finding the percentage of total marks, and dividing it by 25. Less than 2 GPA is considered as a fail!

Final exam is given a weight of .75 and internal marks is given a weight of .25 in this school. Now consider this example..

You scored 20 out of 60 in final exam and 50 as internal marks. Then the maximum marks that can be scored is (60*0.75)+(50*0.25) = 57.5. You have scored a total of 27.5 (47% or 1.9 GPA). Suppose you need 50% to pass, therefore, you've failed.

If your professor wants people with your score to pass, he/she can either increase the  or the weight of your final exam or increase the internal score. It should be noted that increasing weight of final exam influences the change of GPA more than the internal score, due to the weight differences (Calculate yourself... In case of trouble, leave a comment).

Consider **δoutput** as change of total marks,**Δwj** as final exam marks  **Δb** as the internal score. **δoutput/δwj** as rate of change of marks caused by change of weights of final exam, and **δoutput/δb** as the rate of change of marks per change of internal marks, so that you'll get a better idea of what it means.

The rate change of output caused by change of any of the terms namely "Bias" or "Weight" is linear whereas the Sigmoid function is curved!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro on all this, but maybe I can still add value to this conversation.

If you take a look at this [page](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c353.html), you will notice a lot of similarities between the total differential and the equation shown in Michael Nielsons book. Just that we are talking about weights and biases. Since the function depends on both the weights and biases, the error will be affected if we change them.

Let's assume that we have a sigmoid neuron. This sigmoid neuron is connected to just a single input.

$$
output = \sigma(z) = \sigma(w * x + b) \\
\Delta output \approx doutput = \frac{\partial output}{\partial w}\Delta w + \frac{\partial output}{\partial b}\Delta b
$$

The total differential will be a tangent hyperplane and for small values $\Delta$w $\Delta$b the slope will be approximately the same as the actual change of the function at that point. Since the neuron will usually have more than a single input/weight, the partial derivatives for all the other weights have to be added. At this point you will have more than three dimensions and there is no easy way to visualise this any longer. w will now be a vector  $\sigma(\mathbf{w} \dot{} \mathbf{x} + b)$. The extra partial derivatives can conveniently be written as a sum.

$$
doutput = \sum_j \frac{\partial output}{\partial w_j}\Delta w_j + \frac{\partial output}{\partial b}\Delta b
$$

But most of the derivatives in the vector will turn out to be zero.